# App not responding to touch / clicks in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I opened just now an old iOS project of mine and upgraded it for the first time to Xcode 5 and viewed it for the first time in iOS 7. None of the buttons or text fields on my login nib are visible. I am not using autolayout. On the iOS 6 simulator, all is fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: your buttons are using default background color and text color?

Comment: Check the placement of the items, It is possible they got shifted to behind the scrollView.

Comment: The items are inside the scroll view and the scroll view itself does not scroll.

Comment: My UIWindow has a height of 0 and a width of 0.

Comment: Solved, but can't select answer yet.

Comment: I just noticed that your description does not match the title.  My answer below solved the issue summarized in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My UIWindow had no width or height. This was fine in iOS 6, but not in 7.

```
self.window        = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
```

should have been

```
self.window        = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Answer (score 0):

in IOS 7, the UIView's frame has changed, default to full-screen view(extend to status bar, navbar, tab bar etc.). maybe your button and text fields is under status bar or tab bar or tool bar. print out the frame, to see if this is the problem.

Comment: I am not using a Nav bar or a tab bar. The views fill the screen and none are touchable.

Comment: @user1122069 upload the screen shot of the problem view controller

Comment: The problem has been solved, but I haven't been able to select my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before when opening an old project into the new xcode. For me the fix was to disable auto-layout on the UIScrollView in the interface builder. Not sure if it will help you I guess it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Autolayout is disabled on the NIB/Views.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this problem and none of the above answers applied in my case.  It seemingly started happening "overnight" on an app that was working the previous day in the simulator.  Also note that gestures seemed to work but not taps on buttons.

I switched over to the Develop branch and verified that the simulator was working correctly for the last stable build.  I started going through my changes one-line at a time and nothing was standing out as something that could possibly be related until... there was one line changed in my storyboard that just looked "odd".

This line:

```
        <simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination" type="retina4"/>
```

Was replaced with this line:

```
        <simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination" />
```

After some quick googling I remembered testing autolayout for 3.5" devices using the Storyboard button to "Apply Retina 3.5 inch form factor" and had left that enabled.  Toggling back to the 4" form factor reverted the storyboard code mentioned above **and resolved the issue**.  I guess it makes sense that the 'type' is no longer "retina4" but not sure why it would affect the simulator.

My explanation is that somehow the simulator was applying non-retina coordinates to a retina screen so my taps would have worked just not at the same location my buttons were located.  Bug.

Comment: This issue is eight months old. I am not going to evaluate your answer and have accepted my own below for clarity that the issue is closed.